# Am I doing a security breach if I am connecting a MS-Access front end (multiple computers) to a SQL Server back-end?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a MS Access frontend that I would like to install on 5-7 computers, so they can access a SQL Server stored on a shared network drive:

[image]

If possible, is it safe and can my data be corrupted? Otherwise, how I have 5-7 users access the SQL Server simultaneously by using an interface?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I don't understand why you can't give your users installs of SQL Server Management Studio and restrict their access with the correct roles etc...

Comment: Hi! I didn't know that was an option. I started building a database with MS-Access, and then expanded it with SQL-server. Could I use MS-Access with SQL Server Management Studio somehow? I'm sorry if I'm confusing you.

Comment: @Molenpad not everyone is comfortable or capable of using SQL. I believe OP is using Access to create a user interface for end users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they have access to the tables directly with insert, update and/or delete rights then they can corrupt your data. If you prevent this by limiting the access-rights or by an MS-Access application then they can/should not be able to corrupt your data.

About *business rules*. According to Wikipedia: *A business rule is a rule that defines or constrains some aspect of business and always resolves to either true or false.*. These rules can be defined in the database as `constraints` but are more often checked by an application. For example a company can give a discount to a customer only in special cases. Or a client can only be deleted if it has no outstanding payments. If the *business rule* is checked by an application then giving somebody access directly to the tables with *update* and/or *delete* rights can corrupt your data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, if I installed the MS-Access front-end on several computers, and people would use it simultaneously, the server should work properly, preventing corrupt data, right?

Comment: SQL-Server will correctly handle any simultaneous access to the data. For me corrupt data also means that it does not follow the business rules. The business rules will not be guaranteed by SQL-Server.

Comment: Hi Marco! Can I ask you what are the business rules?

Comment: @Johnathan I will add it to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can use MS Access as a front end to SQL Server. Its quite common. I have [done this myself](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?s=0c958e154b6ae52e4408f6dae0469095&p=1452460#post1452460) in the past.

No, Access itself won't corrupt data.  However your Access application needs to be designed so that it respects SQL Server constraints and rules. Also how will your Application stop users from making simple mistakes, like deleting records if they're not permitted to.

The most common problem I had was dealing with concurrency.  When 2 clients are doing things at the same time such as inserting a record. Do you let Access generate the primary key? or do you let SQL Server manage it? In either case after you've inserted rows how do you ensure that each client is still dealing with the same row?

This is a consideration for anyone developing a multi user system. It just takes some time and thought.

Some advice: Make sure that you **define the primary key** in SQL Server. If you don't do this Access won't allow you to update records as it can't guarantee a lock on a single record. Primary keys and indexes also have a huge impact on performance.

Edit: I've just been thinking about your Question title a bit more. You mention "security breach". If security is a concern, You need to consider how users will connect to the database. Domain authentication? or SQL authentication, and how you log actions taken by users.

Comment: Hi Peter! Thank you for your answer. :) Can I ask about what you mean by respecting SQL server constraints and rules? Thank you!

Comment: Primary keys must be unique, foreign key constraints, unique indexes, data must fit datatype. If you don't follow the rules SQL will reject the transaction and return an error to access. For example if you try inserting 2 rows with the same primary key. This is not a problem for SQL but in access it will appear as an error. This is how SQL enforces data integrity.